# Is it possible to run qemu-system-x86_64 virtual machine from raw disk image located on external flash drive?

Tags: permissions, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

For some project I need to have QEMU/KVM virtual machine with raw disk image.
So I have created this raw disk image as simple as

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/disk.img bs=1M count=3092
```

and got 3 Gb of space on it.

Then I have set-up new virtual machine from Virtual Machine Manager (`virt-manager`) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using my normal account. So I have installed the Ubuntu from *mini.iso* to inside the *~/disk.img*. My user is a member of `libvirtd` group. I can boot the VM when virtual disk image is inside my home folder.

Then I moved this file to the external FAT32 (*vfat*) medium which is mounted read-and-write. So it is located inside */media/username/FLASH/disk.img*. I specified this path in the *Virtual Disk* setting section of the virtual machine.

But when I try to start this machine I get the following error message:

> Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2020-01-22T21:45:20.221697Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/media/username/FLASH/disk.img,format=raw,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-1: Could not open '/media/username/FLASH/disk.img': Permission denied

And this message persists even if I run the Virtual Machine Manager as root using `sudo virt-manager`.

The permissions of this file are the following:

> ```
> $ ls -al /media/username/FLASH/disk.img 
> -rw-r--r-- 1 username username 3221225472 Jan 23 00:18 /media/username/FLASH/disk.img
> ```

Also I tried to create a symbolic link using `ln -s /media/username/FLASH/disk.img ~/disk.img` and set machine to use the latter disk path. But it does not work too.

How can I boot QEMU/KVM virtual machine from the disk image located on external storage?

Comment: Hi N0rbert, could it be that the apparmor protection kicks in protecting you a bit too much. Have a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibvirtApparmor#Using_uncommon_paths and let me know if that would be a good answer for your case.

Comment: I have stopped apparmor, but issue persists. What is interesting - executing `qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=/media/username/FLASH/disk.img,format=raw -m 1024` as my normal users boots VM without issues. While `virt-manager` tries to launch it as *libvirt-qemu* user. So seems to be unix-file permissions issue as described in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this permissions issue when running VM's from a thumb drive.

The problem I was having was that my system (Fedora 27) automatically mounts new drives (external HDDs, USB, SD) to

`/run/media/(username)/(device name)` (on your system it's /media/username/....)

For whatever reason this causes the permissions issue. By default it was mounted with `fmask=0022` and `dmask=0022` (use [`man mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mount.8.html) for details). To fix the issue we need to unmount the drive from that location as root, and then mount it to `/mnt`. In the example below the thumb drive is `/dev/sdc1`. We need to remount it with `fmask=0011` to allow write access for all users and groups.

```
# su  -     (then enter root password)
# umount  /run/media/yourusername/devicename
# mount  /dev/sdc1 /mnt -o fmask=0011        (mount usb to /mnt)
```

After that I just made sure to have symbolic links from the original location of the qcow2 drives to the new location (still as root)

```
# cd  /var/lib/libvirt/images
# ln  -s  (new target)  (link name)
```

so if your VM is named MyVM

```
# ln  -s  /mnt/Myvm.qcow2  MyVm.qcow2
```

Once I saw that my VMs were now working, I edited `/etc/fstab` to automatically mount the drive at `/mnt`. The folders and qcow2 drives were owned by my standard user account and group. I am sure there are better ways to do it, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: I have added `fmask=0011` to the mount options and this did the trick. Thank you for the idea and whole method!