# Where default values of fmask and dmask are defined for disk auto-mounter?

Tags: 16.04, mount, systemd, fat32, udisks

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed (with MATE DE if this matters).

After the insertion of USB-flash it is usually got auto-mounted to the `/media/username/VOLUMEID` and the `mount` shows the following information for it:

`/dev/sdc1 on /media/username/VOLUMEID type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)`

Note: this question is logical continuation of my [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1205027/66509).

**How and where can I change the exact values of the default `fmask` and `dmask` mount options?**

I can read `man mount` and use `mount -o fmask=...,dmask=...` but really I'm asking about configuration of the default values for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dmask" and "fmask" mount options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848/dmask-and-fmask-mount-options)

Comment: What's the point of changing dmask and fmask values? Please advise why you want to do that.

Comment: The "duplicate" is outdated. Thanks for minus 1. It is very constructive and useful. Instead please give real solution. And of course, I know how to use `man mount` and `mount -o`.

Comment: Voted to leave this question open: https://askubuntu.com/review/close/1011058

Comment: Read the `man` pages  for `mount
systemctl
systemd.automount
systemd.directives
systemd.mount
systemd
systemd.unit
`

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the same problem on my Debian 10.5 with Mate DE (but I don't know if this is relevant).

While in /etc/fstab was listed the usb device without uid and gid option, udisks2 mount the usb key in /media/usb0 as root. User can read and umount disk but not write on it.
This was my fstab:

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

Commenting out this row done the job.
Now my USB disk is mounted in /media/$USER/samething with the correct permissions.

I hope this help you and all the other posted similar questions (I found a lot of unresolved questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar question for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and `exfat` flash drives, which also mounts with `fmask=0022,dmask=0022` by default which results in all files being marked as executable by default.

Automounting of external flash drives are handled by [UDisks daemon](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) - this is noticeable by `uhelper=udisks2` meta-option listed in `mount` output:

```
$ mount | grep /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1 on /media/user/Sandisk128 type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

UDisks can be [configured](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/2.9.4/mount_options.html) to pass specific mount options for different filesystem types/different devices. Configuration example can be found in `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example`, and based on it I created:

```
$ cat /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf
[defaults]
exfat_defaults=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,fmask=0133,dmask=0022
exfat_allow=uid=$UID,gid=$GID,dmask,errors,fmask,iocharset,namecase,umask
```

Essentially adding `fmask=0133,dmask=0022` to `exfat_defaults` (others `*_defaults`/`*_allow` should be used for other filesystem types, e.g. `vfat_defaults`/`vfat_allow` for `vfat`, see `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example` for examples).

Now restarting the UDisks with `sudo systemctl restart udisks` and re-pluggin the flash drive I see in logs:

```
Apr 13 11:26:55 host udisksd[9586]: Using overridden mount options: uid=$UID,gid=$GID,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,fmask=0133,dmask=0022
```

And applied settings in the mount output:

```
$ findmnt /media/user/Sandisk128
TARGET              SOURCE  FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/user/Sandisk128 /dev/sde1 exfat  rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro
```

---

Answering the question where those defaults are coming from is a bit more interesting.

Mounting `exfat` disk without any options we can trace that no options are passed to the kernel:

```
# strace -e mount -f mount -t exfat /dev/sde1 /mnt/point/
mount("/dev/sde1", "/mnt/point", "exfat", 0, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

but `fmask=0022,dmask=0022` are still present in the options list:

```
$ findmnt /mnt/point
TARGET  SOURCE  FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/point /dev/sde1 exfat  rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro
```

Looking through the kernel sources we can see that `fmask=...,dmask=...` are appended in [`exfat_show_options()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/fs/exfat/super.c#L156) based on `opts->fs_fmask, opts->fs_dmask` values:

```
static int exfat_show_options(struct seq_file *m, struct dentry *root)
{
    ...
    seq_printf(m, ",fmask=%04o,dmask=%04o", opts->fs_fmask, opts->fs_dmask);
```

`fs_fmask`, `fs_dmask` are set in [`exfat_parse_param()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/fs/exfat/super.c#L279) if the relevant mount option is provided (not our case), and otherwise initialized from the current task `umask` in [`exfat_init_fs_context()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/fs/exfat/super.c#L766):

```
static int exfat_init_fs_context(struct fs_context *fc)
{
    ...
    sbi->options.fs_fmask = current->fs->umask;
    sbi->options.fs_dmask = current->fs->umask;
```

We can confirm that Udisks is running with the `umask` of `0022`:

```
$ grep '^Umask:' "/proc/$(pgrep udisksd)/status"
Umask:  0022
```

And manually confirm that changing `umask` of the process will change the used `fmask`/`dmask`, e.g. with `umask 0133`:

```
# umask 0133
# umask -S
u=rw,g=r,o=r
# strace -e mount -f mount -t exfat /dev/sde1 /mnt/point/
mount("/dev/sde1", "/mnt/point", "exfat", 0, NULL) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
# findmnt /mnt/point
TARGET  SOURCE  FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/point /dev/sde1 exfat  rw,relatime,fmask=0133,dmask=0133,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro
# ls -l /mnt/point/README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72 Apr 12 11:40 /mnt/point/README.txt
# mkdir /mnt/point/directory
# ls -ld /mnt/point/directory/
drw-r--r-- 2 root root 131072 Apr 13 11:19 /mnt/point/directory/
# umount /mnt/point
```

I.e. default `fmask`/`dmask` values for `exfat` filesystem are coming from the process `umask` ([the same](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/fs/fat/inode.c#L1143) for `vfat` filesystems).
Since typically we want to have different `fmask`/`dmask` (to make directories executable, and regular field non-executable), the preferred method to customize `fmask`/`dmask` is to explicitly add those options in the UDisks daemon configuration as suggested above.